Scraping multiple pages from a URL that doesnt change using power query
I am new to web scraping. I am working on a project which scrapes data from multiple job websites using PowerBI. Some websites are easy where the url changes with the pages. Other websites are difficult where the website url doesnt change with the pages.
Example: HSBC website is easy to scrape because the url changes with the pages and I use the following code to create a query, and then change the variable - PageStart - as per the page numbers I want to extract.
Code:
(PageStart as text) =>

let Source = Web.BrowserContents("https://mycareer.hsbc.com/en_GB/external/SearchJobs/?pipelineRecordsPerPage=10&pipelineOffset="&PageStart&""),
    #"Extracted Table From Html" = Html.Table(Source, {{"Column1", ".article__header__text__title\-\-8 *"}, {"Column2", ".location"}, {"Column3", ".icon\-\-folder + *"}, {"Column4", ".icon\-\-clock + *"}, {"Column5", ".icon\-\-person + *"}, {"Column6", ".icon\-\-calendar + *"}, {"Column7", ".social-share__text"}, {"Column8", ".link\-\-chevron *"}, {"Column9", ".grid .link\-\-chevron:nth-child(1)"}}, [RowSelector=".article\-\-result"]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Extracted Table From Html",{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}, {"Column4", type text}, {"Column5", type text}, {"Column6", type text}, {"Column7", type text}, {"Column8", type text}, {"Column9", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"

Other websites are difficult where the website url doesnt change with the pages. Example Target's career page with the URL: https://indiajobs.target.com/search-jobs/SetSearchRequestGeoLocation?lat=null&lon=null&IsUsingGeolocation=true&hasHtml5GeoError=false&geoType=ipambientonly
I tried using the developer tools in chrome and under the network tab, I get this Request URL: https://indiajobs.target.com/search-jobs/results?ActiveFacetID=0&CurrentPage=2&RecordsPerPage=15&Distance=50&RadiusUnitType=0&Keywords=&Location=&ShowRadius=False&IsPagination=False&CustomFacetName=&FacetTerm=&FacetType=0&SearchResultsModuleName=Search+Results&SearchFiltersModuleName=Search+Filters&SortCriteria=0&SortDirection=0&SearchType=5&PostalCode=&ResultsType=0&fc=&fl=&fcf=&afc=&afl=&afcf=
But this doesn't work. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
enter image description here

It seems that you can just add &p=2 to the first URL you provided.
But the second URL works perfectly also. What is the problem with it?

For the second URL, when I copy & paste the link address in my browser, I get this: https://i.sstatic.net/JQlD0F2C.png

It's a response in json format, you can convert it in json-document  in power query and then take field with name results. Then you can convert it into a table of text lines, for example, for further processing:
let
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://indiajobs.target.com/search-jobs/results?...")),
WebContent = Source[results],
LineByLine = Lines.FromText(WebContent)
in
LineByLine
